# Having an Event change a variable in the background

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have the following scenario presented to me:

- Authentication runs against AD
- AD Server returns an identity string "foo\bar"
- On successful authentication an event is fired "LOGIN_SUCCESS" with identity string and adapter as parameters

Once this event is fired, there's several triggers attached.

1. First Listener checks if a User-Row in the DB with the matched "identity foo\bar" is already present. If not, a User-Row will be created
2. On every login another Listener will update the User-Metadata provided from the adapter
3. I would like to have a third listener that changes the identity-string "foo\bar" into the user-object from the User-Row in the DB

Currently my `AuthenticationService` looks like this:

```
if ($result->isValid()) {
    $currentIdentity = $result->getIdentity();

    $eventManager = new EventManager(__CLASS__);
    $eventResult = $eventManager->trigger(self::DUIT_USER_LOGIN_SUCCESSFUL, $this, [
        'identity' => $currentIdentity,
        'adapter' => $adapter
    ]);

    // This whole stuff sucks!
    if ($eventResult->last() instanceof EventInterface) {
        $identityObject = $eventResult->last()->getParam('identity');

        if ($identityObject instanceof User) {
            $this->getStorage()->write($identityObject);

            return $result;
        }
    }

    $this->getStorage()->write($result->getIdentity());
}
```

As you can see I do stuff here that doesn't really belong in the `AuthenticationService`. Is there any way that an `Event` is able to modify a given `parameter` (in this case `identity`) so that the value of the parameter is changed in the background?

I really don't want to do this eventResult checking in the `AuthenticationService`. This assumption just shouldn't be there, but I really don't see any different way to do things.

//Edit

Currently the trigger is doing this inside the background:

```
public function handleWorkflow(EventInterface $event)
{
    $identityString = $event->getParam('identity');

    $userObject = $this->userService->findByActiveDirectoryId($identityString);

    if ($userObject instanceof User) {
        return $event->setParam('identity', $userObject);
    }

    return $event->setParam('identity', $identityString);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed on IRC, this kind of "transformation" applied to the event data is subtle and will bite you back.

If you expect a `string` from your event data, then do code a `IdentityFinder` or something like that and inject it into your `AuthenticationService` instead:

```
if ($result->isValid()) {
    $currentIdentity = $result->getIdentity();

    // we use some sort of locator to find the identity
    $identity = $this->identityLocator->find($currentIdentity);

    $this->getStorage()->write($identity);

    // triggering is still OK, but not to manipulate the data here.
    // it should also happen _AFTER_ successful authentication
    // I also assume you injected the EventManager here, instead of building it
    // result is also being ignored, it shouldn't contain data required to us
    $this->eventManager->trigger(
        self::DUIT_USER_LOGIN_SUCCESSFUL, 
        $this,
        [
            'identity' => $identity,
            'adapter' => $adapter
        ]
    );

}
```

If the result is still what was passed in, then make this finder no-op by just implementing a dummy one:

```
class NoopIdentityFinder implements IdentityFinderInterface
{
    public function find($identity)
    {
        return $identity; // no real "find" going on
    }
}
```

In this way you code your logic explicitly and easy to understand, by still allowing event listeners to "catch" what happened.